# cannot download snapshot from nexus

Tags: maven, maven-3, nexus

I set up a nexus repo for maven, I have deployed a snapshot but I can't get it anyway. No problem on release version.

[Snapshot in the repo](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FX4HK.png)

[what I get in my local repo](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PbDUC.png)

[cannot get the jar](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qiYde.png)

[can get the metadata](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3dVUJ.png)

Maven Setting

```
<mirror>
    <id>maven-public</id>
    <mirrorOf>*</mirrorOf>
    <name>maven-public</name>
    <url>http://nexus:8081/repository/maven-public/</url>
</mirror>

<profile>
    <id>nexus</id>
    <repositories>
        <repository>
            <id>public</id>
            <name>maven-public</name>
            <url>http://nexus:8081/repository/maven-public/</url>
            <releases>
                <enabled>true</enabled>
            </releases>
            <snapshots>
                <enabled>true</enabled>
            </snapshots>
        </repository>           
    </repositories>
    <pluginRepositories>
        <pluginRepository>
            <id>public</id>
            <url>http://nexus:8081/repository/maven-public/</url>
            <releases><enabled>true</enabled></releases>
            <snapshots><enabled>true</enabled></snapshots>
        </pluginRepository>
    </pluginRepositories>
</profile>
```

Answer (score 0):

If the metadata is getting cached . try using mvn -U to the update the cached local repository.